# Simple animation change height without jquery

Tags: javascript, animation

I need simple animation on simple js. I think jquery too much for that. I need to increase or decrease the height of the block by pressing the buttons, but this work only on Opera (.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9DCA5/)

```
function global_animate(element, property_to_map, duration, callback) {
   duration = duration || 1000;
   var delta = function (a) { return a; };
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var property_from_map = {};
    var property_units_map = {};

    for (var property in property_to_map) {
        property_from_map[property] = window.getComputedStyle(element, null)[property] || element.currentStyle[property];
        property_units_map[property] = parseUnits(property_from_map[property]);
        property_from_map[property] = parseInt(property_from_map[property]);
        property_to_map[property] = parseInt(property_to_map[property]);
    }

    function parseUnits(a) {
        try {
        return a.match(/^\d+(\w{2}|%);?$/i)[1];
        } catch (e) {
        return "";
        }                   
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
    var now = (new Date().getTime()) - start;
    var progress = now / duration; 

    for (var property in property_to_map) {
        var result = (property_to_map[property] - property_from_map[property]) * delta(progress) + property_from_map[property];
        element.style[property] = result.toFixed(2) + property_units_map[property];
    }

    if (progress < 1)
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10);
    else
        if (typeof callback == 'function')
        callback();
    }, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the regexp from

```
alert("23.2px".match(/^\d+(\w{2}|%);?$/i));​ // alert null
```

to something like this

```
alert("23.2px".match(/^\d+\.*\d*(\w{2}|%);?$/i));​ // alert ["23.2px", "px"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in your regex: `a.match(/^\d+(\w{2}|%);?$/i)[1];`. The second time it runs it does’t catch the units properly.

If I hard code the units to 'px', it works for me (in chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/9DCA5/5/

Maybe you can debug from there?

Answer (score 0):

Method getComputedStyle() is not supported in IE, which uses the "currentStyle" property instead.